# Daylight savings time for GPX and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, xml, postgresql, time, dst

So here I'm working with gpx files. Take note of an excerpt of one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- GPSTrack 2.2.1 — http://bafford.com/gpstrack -->
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1">
<trk>
<name><![CDATA[2016-03-31 10-17-54]]></name>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="38.704859" lon="-8.970304"><ele>13.050667</ele><time>2016-03-31T09:17:51Z</time><!-- hAcc=95.768176 vAcc=10.000000 --></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="38.704894" lon="-8.970324"><ele>13.050667</ele><time>2016-03-31T09:17:55Z</time><!-- hAcc=141.087476 vAcc=10.000000 --></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="38.704859" lon="-8.970304"><ele>13.050667</ele><time>2016-03-31T09:17:55Z</time><!-- hAcc=95.768176 vAcc=10.000000 --></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="38.704878" lon="-8.970343"><ele>13.150488</ele><time>2016-03-31T09:18:43Z</time><!-- hAcc=165.000000 vAcc=10.000000 --></trkpt>
```

See the name of the file? It gives us the time 10H17. Now check the time for each point. It's counted with one less hour.

I still don't get how the times are messed up here. But this is the beginning of the problem.

Now, I'm parsing these many gpx files, and loading them into a PostgreSQL database. More specifically this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trips (
  trip_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

  start_location TEXT REFERENCES locations(label),
  end_location TEXT REFERENCES locations(label),

  start_date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  end_date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,

  bounds geography(POLYGONZ, 4326) NOT NULL,
  points geography(LINESTRINGZ, 4326) NOT NULL,

  timestamps TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE[] NULL
);
```

Even while using `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` the points are being loaded with the wrong hour (one less hour). This happens only in the days after the Daylight Savings Time is in effect. The point here: is there any way to check if a date is on DST time and add one hour to it if that checks?

I checked for `tm_isdst` and `datetime.dst()` but I still don't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *know* the ***time zone name*** where this local time is supposed to be set in (assuming *'Europe/Vienna'* in the example), you can normalize the value to correct UTC time (or *any* other time zone) with this expression:

```
SELECT '2016-03-31T09:17:51Z'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Vienna' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

Result:

```
timezone
--------------------
2016-03-31 07:17:51
```

Yes, apply `AT ZIME ZONE` *twice*.

Since you seem to be dealing with different time zones I would consider using `timestamptz` instead of `timestamp` in your tables.

Be sure to use time zone ***names***, not abbreviations or plain time offsets to get precise adjustments for DST.
<sub>I hate the moronic concept of "daylight saving time" - it never saves any daylight but keeps wasting valuable time of people being confused by it.</sub>

Detailed explanation for all of that:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)
- [How to get a time zone from a location using latitude and longitude coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates/16086964#16086964)

Comment: well, although I agree with you on DST wasting us time, it sure is nice to have one more hour of sun during the summer haha.

So, regarding my problem, I understood your answer, and I changed my table to have `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. Although the date is collected in the same country, this DST bore is taken as a timezone.
Using the `pgAdmin` tool I now see that my table shows the date like this
`2016-03-31 09:17:51+01`. This means that when I query for the date and pass it to whatever function I want, it will consider it as 10:17, right?

Comment: @Shoplifter.Doe: [As explained in the linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170), the *display* of `timestamptz` is adapted to the time zone setting of the session. You can always use the `AT TIME ZONE` construct once more to get the display for a given time zone. When you *cast* to `date`, the current time zone setting is taken into consideration as well.

Comment: Yeah I got it. The time zone setting of the session is more than enough. "Daylight Saving Time is not among the brightest ideas humanity ever came up with." - for programming issues this is the case indeed.

For me the `SELECT start_date::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' from trips` expression is the one that works for me. Much like your "loaded footgun" from the linked answer.

In my front-end I can deal with these dates easily with some JS libraries.

I was far from knowing that these timezones can be a pain. Thank you for the lesson.